# Creating objects in C++ not using "new"

Tags: c++, object, new-operator, delete-operator

I want to make a program that lets say represents a matrix
now the matrix will be represented by a vector that each object in the vector will 
represent a cell  example: vector
now when constructing the matrix the constructor receives a list of cells to insert in the matrix. **The size of the list is unknown in compilation time**

I am interested in creating this matrix without using memory on the heap. In other words not creating object using the word "new" or "delete"
is there any way to do that if I don't know how many objects are meant to be inserted into the vector?

Comment: _Why_ are you opposed to allocating this object on the heap?  This is what the heap is for (well, one of the primary things, at least).

Comment: Why do you think it's a good idea to avoid the heap? What if the matrix will be very large and non-sparse, thus not being able to fit on the stack?

Comment: Unless you have a very specific reason for avoiding `new` this sounds like a baaaad idea.

Comment: ahh.. you guys are right but..i am a student and that is the requirement of the exercise that i am doing, the goal is to learn how to use the standert library - so apperantly by using "vector" i can avoid using memory on the heap. i just have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @kevin:  So, are you trying to use `std::vector`?  That would make a lot more sense.

Comment: std::vector probably doesn't actually avoid any heap usage, but at least you don't need to manage it yourself.

Comment: @kevin, you are way off track here, google std::vector, or review your notes.

Comment: @Matt:  std::vector does indeed allocate memory on the heap.

Comment: `std::vector` is internally using the heap, but you don't have to create the vector object itself on the heap. Maybe that's where the confusion stems from?

Answer (score 2):

There is a special way to use new to allocate memory in the stack or as static storage using what is called the *placement new operator*. With this version of new, you reserve a chunk of memory and the you explicitly tell new where you want to store a specific variable. It would work as follows:

```
   #include <new>
   int main()
   {
      char buffer[500];  // chunk of memory
      int p*;
      p = new (buffer) int[10];
   }
```

Note that you need to include the *new* header in order to use this special new operator. In this case, as you are using automatic storage, the memory will be freed upon leaving the block in which it was declared (the main).

*References: C++ Primer plus. Chapter 9. Page 420*

Comment: `buffer` is not guaranteed to be suitably aligned for `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It felt strange seeing that example in the book :)

Comment: But this uses the word 'new'. OP wants no 'new'-ness or 'delete'-ness. Not downvoting for now!

Comment: I think what he meant by that statement was that he did not want to use the heap, and thus the standard dynamic memory allocator new and deallocator delete. With placement new you don't necessarilly allocate dynamic memory and you don't need to use delete to free you memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to do this without performing direct (and thus platform-dependent) manipulation of the program's/function's stack frame using assembly instructions - which I would heartily discourage. What's stopping you from using the heap?

Answer (score 1):

Use `alloca` to obtain a pointer and then use the in-place `new` operator:

```
void *p = alloca(sizeof(Class));
new (p) Whatever(arguments);
```

However, **do** read `alloca` manual page before using it! **Be very careful**. As Jim Brissom says, `alloca` isn't portable.

You don't need to `delete`. The memory will be freed when the function returns

Comment: Wrap such resource management up. Doing memory management by hand == bad.

Comment: Portability concerns aside, is the pointer returned by `alloca` guaranteed to be correctly aligned for `Whatever`?

Comment: The class destructor won't be called when the function returns. If the class has any pointers you're probably making a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, it's very limiting and very unorthodox.  You'll need to create a statically sized array of `unsigned char` which form a memory pool.  There will be a limit to the size of the list of objects.  You'll need to overload a `new` operator (and `delete` operator) for that class to specifically target such a memory pool.

That said, there's really no good reason to go this route.

Comment: IIRC, placement new as you describe is pretty common in the Windows Printer DDK.

Comment: In fact, I think that is the Right Way to put an object onto the heap at a location where it can't be paged out, if that's at all necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't want to use memory on the heap, where else do you want to get it from?

a) system dependant - you can ask the operating system to allocate some memory for you. But this is bad style (system dependant), and will use the same RAM... just in a different way allocated. For example, ::GlobalAlloc or ::LocalAlloc in Windows 32 will do such things if you are really interested in doing that.

b) memory mapped files - that might be interesting if you are asking because you think you'll have not enough RAM available and access time isn't an issue.

c) resort to C functions like malloc/free and cast the pointers... that is getting memory from the heap, just avoiding the "new" and "delete" keywords.

However, it is hard to tell what a "good" solution without information *why* you want to avoid new / delete.
You have need for dynamic memory allocation, these two are the tools to do that.

Could you please explain/rephrase your question so you can get more precise answers?